# The "hot" observable doesn't work when setting time delay in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I'm writing a unit test with ngrx for effect, when I run the test with hot observable on the effect which has `delay` on pipe chain, the `receive` has an empty value.

```
const output = loginSuccess(loginResult);

actions$ = hot('^a', { a: action });
const expected = cold('30ms c', { c: output })

expect(effect.login$).toBeObservable(expected);
```

My function is:

```
login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(login),
      delay(20),
      map((payload) => loginSuccess({
        data: {
          username: payload.credential.username,
          age: 18,
          name: 'name',
        },
      }))
    )
  );
```

It works fine if I remove the `delay` operator (and correct the time in the test case), what I did wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the test scheduler.
See the NgRx docs for an example - https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing#effects-with-parameters

```
effects.search$({
  scheduler: getTestScheduler(),
});
```